# Query to Round the numbers (ex: 300.501 to 300.500)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I have a requirement in the following way:(need SQL query)
- If the input is 300.501, then output should be 300.500
- If 300.503 then output should be 300.505
- If 300.507 then output should be 300.505
- If 300.508 then output should be 300.510

So, basically I think it is rounding to the nearest 5

Tried several rounding functions but did Not succeed. Do we need to truncate the last digit and should change the entire number accordingly?

Comment: You'd do it just like you would in regular arithmetic. Divide by 5. Round the result. Multiply by 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data rounded to the nearest 0.005 (1/200) multiply it by 200, round it, and then divide by 200 e.g.

```
SELECT ROUND(300.501*200) / 200, ROUND(300.503*200) / 200
```

Output:

```
ROUND(300.501*200) / 200    ROUND(300.503*200) / 200
300.5000                    300.5050
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df32dc16449566c3c48b332bcada721e)

Comment: Why the downvote? Does this not produce exactly the result OP asked for, using an SQL query?